# JavaFX tableview scrollbar event not firing

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, scrollbar

I have added an event handler for scrolling to my tableview but it only works when I scroll using the scroll wheel, but I need it to work when you click and drag with the scroll bar as well. Any ideas whats wrong? I tried using different methods for the event but none of them have worked.

Heres my code:

```
tableVw.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ScrollEvent scrollEvent) {
        System.out.println("scrolling");
    }
});
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You should add more information.

Comment: Such as? When I click on the scrollbar and scroll through the table the text "scrolling" isnt printed but when I scroll using the mouse wheel it is.

Comment: Scroll Events are low-level events representing a scroll gesture with the mouse (or similar input device). They don't represent semantic "scrolling actions" such as interaction with a control that initiates scrolling via a mouse click, drag, or keyboard action. I don't see any nice way to get at this. You could perform a lookup to get the scroll bars, and register listeners with their `valueProperty`s, but that is pretty ugly.

Comment: Also, I wonder why you need to know when the table scrolls. It's possible that there's another way to do what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: It is ugly indeed, but the only way to get TableView working properly. It's not the best table implementation around...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks James_D.
The code that worked:

```
scrollbar.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
        // Stuff with scrollbar here
    }
});
```

To get the scroll bar I used:

```
public static ScrollBar getVerticalScrollbar(TableView<?> table) {
    ScrollBar result = null;
    for(Node n : table.lookupAll(".scroll-bar")) {
        if(n instanceof ScrollBar) {
            ScrollBar bar = (ScrollBar) n;
            if(bar.getOrientation().equals(Orientation.VERTICAL)) {
                result = bar;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I don't know if its the best solution but it works.